# Unexpected result when using TensorFlow matmul, dtype=tf.float32

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Using tensorflow 2.3.0, python 3.8.11.

Here is the code:

```
a = tf.constant([2, 2, 3, 3], shape=[2, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
print('-------------------')
print(a)

a2 = tf.matmul(a,a)
print('-------------------')
print(a2)
```

the output as below (get other wrong results on different runs):

```
-------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[2. 2.]
 [3. 3.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
-------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[10. 10.]
 [ 0.  0.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

But if set dtype as int32 or float64, get correct result, float64 result  as below:

```
-------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[2. 2.]
 [3. 3.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float64)
-------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[10. 10.]
 [15. 15.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float64)
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.matmul` is working fine with `Tensorflow 2.6.0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([2, 2, 3, 3], shape=[2, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
print('-------------------')
print(a)

a2 = tf.matmul(a,a)
print('-------------------')
print(a2)
```

**Output**

```
-------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[2. 2.]
 [3. 3.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
-------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[10. 10.]
 [15. 15.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```